# How to move an application to Cassandra?

Tags: mysql, database, cassandra, database-migration, cassandra-2.0

This is probably a stupid question, but I've just started interning at a company and I'm supposed to figure out how to migrate a large C-based algorithmic application from MySQL to Cassandra (I'm completely new to all this). I've been looking up how I would approach this for a day now, but I'm still a bit unclear. I see that to operate in Cassandra, the data should be denormalized. Also, there are several tools for migrating data from MySQL to Cassandra like Sqoop or the Bulk Loader.

So my question is: to move this application to Cassandra, am I supposed to change every SQL statement and table to Cassandra, perhaps using Datastax's C Driver? Or do I just add something to the application that writes the MySQL Data to a keyspace in Cassandra as the application is running, like it says [here](https://www.hakkalabs.co/articles/migrate-mysql-cassandra-without-downtime)?

A vast majority of resources I've found just show how to move data to Cassandra, as opposed to an entire application's logic. Also, most resources I've found seem to be outdated - it seems that because newer versions of Cassandra have approximately equal read and write rates, my impression is that there isn't a huge need to completely denormalize the data.

FYI: The current data is stored in approximately thirty tables of statistics aggregated from wireless access points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need application changes. Data read / write code is very different between cassandra and mysql. You'll be able to a lot of queries in mysql that you won't be able to in cassandra - cassandra requires data to be modelled in a way that supports efficient querying using its (compared to sql) limited query language, CQL.

Is your data relational? Are joins being used? Or is it mostly key-value data, possibly in a time series? If it's statistics, and without joins, it might be considerably easier than otherwise.

You'll need to model your cassandra data model according to the queries that your application (and possibly other applications) use. You can then create the cassandra schema, and export / import the mysql data. For that you can use tools like Pentaho, or even write a migration application. How much data is there currently in the database? If it's not too much, you might be able to get away with csv export and import.

You're application will need to change. Change the application to read and write to cassandra. Can you tolerate downtime? If not, consider the approaches outlined in the link you posted.

This is not a trivial undertaking. Depending on the data model currently in mysql, this might be a major undertaking.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! There is no existing data that needs to be migrated - as of now, the application itself inserts simulated data into the tables and runs the algorithm on these test cases.

Comment: Also, as far as I know, there do not seem to be any joins in the application. The queries are rather simple select statements like "select type, width from ap_radios where ((ap_mac=y) and (id=x))".

Comment: And sorry, what exactly do you mean by downtime? This isn't a very rushed project - I'm given a month to at least plan the migration and begin it. And for changing the actual queries in the application, is the Datastax C driver the only way to go about it?

Comment: Seems like it shouldn't be too difficult. You'll need to learn about cassandra and how to use it. It is very different to relational databases. There's free training available online at datastax.com, and it's very very good. In terms of actual queries, it depends on which language you're using. In most cases, if there's an official datastax driver, that would be the one to use. Also, if you need analytics on the data that can't be met by cql queries, you'll need to use Spark with the Spark Cassandra Connector from DataStax.

Comment: Oh...realised I didn't answer your question. Downtime is when you have to take a running application down in order to redeploy, or when the applications crashed and nobody can use it. In your case, the existing app isn't really doing anything; so it shouldn't be an issue.